# Create SharePoint web page outside of document library

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, html, document-library

I'm reasonably new to SharePoint 2007 and trying to move from an ASP.NET to SharePoint way of thinking has been an interesting experience!

I would like to create a page at the same level as the default.aspx page in a subsite. The "SharePoint way" of doing things involves putting the page into a document library. I am reluctant to do this as the breadcrumb navigation of the page then includes the name of the libarary but I would like the library to be transparent to the user.

I can create a page in the right place in SharePoint designer but I can't find a way to use a SharePoint template. I have tried copying the default.aspx page, but the navigation linkes are not updated.

Am I missing something or can someone suggest a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't seem to be possible. Subsites can be used to be categorise content by topic, but they can't be used very much.

Answer (score 2):

I see what you are saying. I would like to share my thoughts on how I will do it.

1. If the Breadcrumb is your only reason why you want to  move to a different than lib, the I recommend you to override the ContentPlaceholder that has the BreadCrumb in your Page, so that BreadCrumb wont be there. But URL will be there for the User to Guess ./DocLib/default.aspx.
2. And if the reason to hide the document library is to make sure that you don't want to allow the user to get into the Lib and change something. I recommend you strip out the permission from the Document Lib and give all the user ReadOnly and add the user with more right who you thing will need to edit the pages.
3. And finally you wanted to it in a Place, you can try deploying them as a Feature that will  provision the pages as Ghostable rather then GhostableInLibray.

While 1,3 cab be packaged in a WSP. 2 one needs bit of a Manual / custom Code if you are trying to automate the process.

Steps to create Ghostable pages you can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/474182/sharepoint-personalization-with-application-pages)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I do like the bread crumb navigation, however including the doc library in it is unnecessary and a distraction to users who don't need to know how the pages are stored.